# Linking CXX shared library

Tags: cmake, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to get Utopia Documents installed from source.. Have managed to get all the dependencies and stuff sorted out and am only left with this nasty dynamic linking (CMake) error :

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../../Utopia.app/Contents/Libraries/libutopia2_qt.dylib
Linking CXX shared library ../../../Utopia.app/Contents/Libraries/libutopia2_auth.dylib
Linking CXX shared library ../../Utopia.app/Contents/Libraries/libcrackle.dylib

[ 44%] Built target utopia2_qt
make: *** [all] Error 2

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3810696602.dir/CheckSymbolExists.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec3810696602/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: You did not post the actual linking error.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that

Comment: There is still nothing shown. make try with VERBOSE=1